# Updating macbook from 10.6.0 to 10.6.8

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

I am trying to update my macbook to 10.6.8. I tried to update to 10.6.8 directly but it does not update it directly so I am going in a sequential manner now. Firstly, I updated it to 10.6.1 by downloading the update to my macbook. Next, I updated it to 10.6.2 and doing so again and again I have updated my laptop to 10.6.4. Is there any better(faster) way I can get my macbook updated to 10.6.8? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you would use the latest combo update for 10.6, which should update you completely to the current version in one shot.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US